# Hide Sidebar with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I hide my sidebar div with a call like this:

```
<script>
  hideSidebar();
</script>
```

My sidebar HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Element.style.display` if it is a **pure JavaScript**:

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<script>
  function hideSidebar() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar")[0].style.display = "none";
  }
  hideSidebar();
</script>
```

And if you are using **jQuery**, you can do:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<script>
  function hideSidebar() {
    $(".sidebar").hide();
  }
  hideSidebar();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put all your `<script>` before the closing body tag in order to make sure your elements are read by the JS parser and ready to be manipulated:

```
<div class="sidebar">
<h1>Content</h1>
<p>Content</p>
</div>


<script>
    function hideSidebar(){
         document.querySelector(".sidebar").style.display = "none";
    }
    hideSidebar();
</script>

</body>
```

or use a DOM ready function (**jQuery**):

```
<script>
    jQuery(function( $ ){ // DOM ready and $ alias secured


        function hideSidebar(){
             $(".sidebar").hide();
        }

        hideSidebar();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Hide function of Jquery -

```js
$('.sidebar').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">

<h1>Content</h1>
<p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, but is there a cleaner code? like calling the function?

Comment: Put the code to any of function it will work as expected I think this is the way easiest or cleaner way to hide element.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be creating a function named `hideSideBar`:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
   hideSidebar();

  function hideSidebar(){
    $('.sidebar').hide();
  }

  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="sidebar">
   <h1>Content</h1>
   <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

**add Script**

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function(){
 $(".sidebar").css("display","none");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.